# Invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: _http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, fdt

I  tried using FDT 5 free version with Flex sdk 4.6 + Air SDk 3.4.
   Getting this error while publishing the ActionScript file

Invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: _http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4

Comment: What is giving you that error?  The Flex compiler?  Or something else?  The error leads me to believe that you are not using the AIR 3.4 SDK.  Flex 4.6 does not ship w/ AIR 3.4.  Did you merge the AIR 3.4 SDK into Flex 4.6 yourself?  Are you sure you did it correctly?

Comment: http://www.swfgeek.net/2012/11/07/combined-version-of-the-flex-4-6-and-air-3-5-sdk-for-the-lazy-ones/

Comment: I tried using the combined version and compile but still facing issues

Comment: I would suggest merging SDK yourself (or just download the latest from Adobe) - who knows what someone else did to the SDK you downloaded